# Python While/for/if statements

Tags: python, loops, printing, while-loop

I wrote a program that multiplies input number by 127. The input doesn't accept alpha as well as number 9.

Besides number 9, it doesn't allow any number that contains 9 e.g. 99, 19 etc. Can we overcome this?

Also, if I type "99", it prints `"Banned number"` two times. Is this co-related with the first statement?

```
banned_number = "9"
while True:
    number = input("number ")

    for items in number:
        if items in banned_number:
            print ("Banned number.")
        elif number.isalpha():
            print ("Sorry, numbers only.")
        elif number.isdigit():
            a = int(number)
            print(a* 127)
```

I know this program is useless, which it clearly is - I went off track when exercising loops and this is the final shape. Is there any way to make this code shorter? Can we make both elif's obsolete with a simple code?

I would appreciate your patience as I've only started Python last week, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the lexical comparison will fetch you incorrect results in terms of numbers as strings.

So, if you are interested in specific types to be checked, you need to compare `int` with `int` and `str` with `str` to get correct results.

You can use `isinstance(a,type)` to check for datatypes of values, which is the `canonical way` of doing this. You can do something like this :

```
banned_number = [9, 1]

while True:
    input_num = input("number ")
    # This will work for both Python 2.x and Python 3.x
    try : 
        number = int(input_num)
    except :
        number = input_num

    if number in banned_number:
        print ("Banned number.")
    elif isinstance(number, str):
        print ("Sorry, numbers only.")
    elif (isinstance(number, int) or isinstance(number, float)):
        a = int(number)
        print(a* 127)
```

This will result in :

```
# for input 9
Banned number. 

# for input 'a'
Sorry, numbers only.

# for input 99
12573
```

Also, the reason why it is printing twice for input `'99'` because this will be treated as two-character string `'9' and '9'` and hence was printing `Banned number.` twice while looping.

Comment: ## elif isinstance(number, str):## is failing us. "number" is sourced from input, which is str, hence we can't get beyond this line? Thank you.

Comment: This answer seems to be using Python 2.x, since it expects `input()` to return a number.

Comment: Edited to support both Python 2 and Python 3. I was using Python 2 and you seem to be using Python 3.

Comment: Thank you for your support - works perfect. I will do some exercises on try/except & isinstance to comprehend them fully.

Comment: You can refer to this link for help - http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/isinstance.html

Answer (score -3):

Take the logic out of the loop, and invert the membership check:

```
banned_number = "9"
while True:
    number = input("number ")
    if banned_number in number:
        print ("Banned number.")
    elif number.isalpha():
        print ("Sorry, numbers only.")
    elif number.isdigit():
        a = int(number)
        print(a* 127)
```

Comment: Say we have two different banned numbers, 9 and 1. How can we proceed then? If we revert it back to for loop, is there anyway to make it stop printing "Banned number" twice if we type 11, 99 etc? Thank you.

Comment: @Ramon - That would be `banned_number not in number and other_number not in number`, or the more general `not any(n in number for n in banned_numbers)`, or `set(number) - set(banned_numbers) == set(number)`. And there's no reason for this to use a loop.